# How to write a file using the argparse and csv libraries in Python?

Tags: python, csv, argparse

I'm creating a report generator using Python, and I'm trying to read and write the file names from the command line. For example, I want to be able to generate output files (with names I type in the command line), such as:

```
python generator.py -p product.csv -s sales.csv --p product_report.csv
```

Here, `generator.py` is the Python script, and I'm reading two files `product.csv` and `sales.csv`. In the script, I calculate revenue, and I want to output the result in the `product_report.csv` file. My current code looks like this:

```
import csv
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("-p", type=argparse.FileType("r"))
parser.add_argument("-s", type=argparse.FileType("r"))
parser.add_argument("--p", type=argparse.FileType('w', encoding='UTF-8'))
args = parser.parse_args()
args_write_report = parser.parse_args(["--p"])

with args.p as Product, args.s as Sales, args_write_report as ProductReport:

    calculated_revenue= {'apple': '1000', 'banana': '22224'}

    writer_product = csv.writer(ProductReport)
    writer_product.writerow(['Product', 'GrossRevenue'])
    
    for key, value in calculated_revenue.items():
        writer_product.writerow([key, value])
```

And I run the command line, I get this error:

```
generator.py: error: argument --p: expected one argument
```

I tried searching for the `argparse` writing function, but because I'm using the `csv` library, I thought I could just create an empty file using the `argparse` function (for the output file name), and continue to use `csv` to write output in that file. But this is not working, and I don't quite understand the error message either.
How can I write a file using the `csv` library with the name from the command line using `argparse`?

Comment: —p is not an optional but is a positional argument (because of the two -s) so you _shouldn’t_ put `—p` in the command line.

Comment: If you have a problem writing csv files that’s a separate question, but reading the documentation will probably help as it has helpful examples https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv

Comment: @barny Actually I don't have a problem with writing the CSV files.. Before I just used ```with open as ProductReport``` and it was working fine. But now I want the user to be able to name the file by entering the command line using ```argparse``` and that's where I'm having the problem.

Comment: An alternative to struggling with the `FileType`, is to just use `argparse` to accept file names - for input and output.  `FileType` produces an `opened` file which doesn't work well in a `with` context.

Comment: `parser.parse_args(["--p", "filename"])` is great for testing, but for production use you want to take the flag and name from the commandline.  You know how to do that, don't you?  Otherwise there's little purpose to using `argparse`.

Comment: I'd definitely recommend the `click` library. I't easy to use and with all the functions you need. https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/ Just write a function and decorate it with click. I can make an suitable example

Comment: Oops, I see you do use `args = parser.parse_args()` and a full command line.  Then what's the purpose of that `args_write_report = parser.parse_args(["--p"])` line?  That's the one that causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code, with an added `print(args)` line produces:

```
1338:~/mypy$ touch product.csv
1339:~/mypy$ touch sales.csv
1339:~/mypy$ python3 stack65636491.py -p product.csv -s sales.csv --p product_report.csv
Namespace(p=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='product_report.csv' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>, s=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='sales.csv' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>)
usage: stack65636491.py [-h] [-p P] [-s S] [--p P]
stack65636491.py: error: argument --p: expected one argument
```

Note that `args.p` is a open file with write mode.  That comes from the '--p' argument.  args.s' is a open read file.  The '--p' argument has overwritten the '-p' argument (they have same `dest`)

The error comes the surplus `parser.parse_args(["--p"])` line.

Change these lines:

```
parser.add_argument("-r", type=argparse.FileType('w', encoding='UTF-8'))
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
#args_write_report = parser.parse_args(["--p"])

with args.p as Product, args.s as Sales, args.r as ProductReport:
```

and test:

```
1344:~/mypy$ python3 stack65636491.py -p product.csv -s sales.csv -r product_report.csv
Namespace(p=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='product.csv' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>, r=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='product_report.csv' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>, s=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='sales.csv' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>)
1345:~/mypy$ cat product_report.csv 
Product,GrossRevenue
apple,1000
banana,22224
```

Now it opens 3 files without stepping on each other, and proceeds to write the new one.

===

A simpler version without `FileType`:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-r")
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)

with open(args.r, 'w') as ProductReport:
    calculated_revenue= {'apple': '1000', 'banana': '22224'}

    writer_product = csv.writer(ProductReport)
    writer_product.writerow(['Product', 'GrossRevenue'])
    
    for key, value in calculated_revenue.items():
        writer_product.writerow([key, value])
```